# regex for matching an entire line $0 in awk

Tags: awk, osx, regular-expression

I need some help or advice wrt `awk` and its use of regular expressions. I have a data input file with an irregular structure. To parse this file correctly I need to recognize a line of the following form:

```
@ 8/1/17, 10:04 PM
```

A line with this pattern marks the end of a complete transaction. It's simply a date & time stamp preceded by a space and the `@` character.

I've cobbled a regular expression that seems to match in "most" usage:

```
\W\@\W[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\,\W[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\W[AP]M
```

However, it does not seem to match when used in the following `awk` statement:

```
$ awk 'match($0, /\W\@\W[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\,\W[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{2}\W[AP]M/) {print $0}' testfile2.txt
```

My system (**macos mojave**) has an old version of `awk`  `awk version 20070501`.

I've also found:

- `grep -e` fails to match this pattern to any line in `testfile2.txt`, but `egrep` and `grep -E` do match the lines I expected them to match.
- `awk 'match($0, /\@/) {print $0}' testfile2.txt` does match (& print) the expected lines, but I can't rely on a single character!

Here's testfile2.txt:

> +13054261988: Forwarding data to primary repository
>    @ 1/7/18, 4:21 PM
>   +16744774911: Use this URL: https://www.repo-prime.ga/
>    @ 1/7/18, 4:22 PM
>   +13054261988: Will do. Passwords OK?
>    @ 1/7/18, 6:12 PM
>   +16744774911: No, use 2FA for all transactions
>    @ 1/7/18, 8:56 PM
>   +13054261988: Using Google's authenticator?
>
> If so, will need additional information.
>    @ 1/7/18, 9:36 PM
>   +13054261988: RSVP ASAP, I have transactions that need to be uploaded.
>    @ 1/7/18, 9:46 PM

Is my regular expression failing to match in `awk` usage due to an error I can't see in my `awk` statement, or is it due to the regex itself, a combination of both, etc?

Comment: Related: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: What does "seems to match in "most" usage" mean? How did you test it?

Comment: @ilkkachu: It works in `egrep` and `grep -E`, but not `grep -e` on macos. Also works in 'BBEdit v 13'.

Comment: @steeldriver: That seems to be it. `macos` has a different set of expressions than my Linux distro (where something similar worked). Actually, it seems that `macos` may be inconsistent between (for example) `awk` and `egrep`/`grep -E`. Making progress now!

Comment: `awk '$1=="@" && $4 ~/^[AP]M$/'` or `awk '/@.*\<[AP]M\>/'` could probably be enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that very old versions of awk had not `{…}` capability.

This older regex syntax should match in any awk:

```
awk '/@ [0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]?, [1-2]?[0-9]:[0-6][0-9] [AP]M/' file
```

If your awk could match bracket expressions like `[[:blank:]]`, the regex could be made to be a little more flexible:

```
awk '/@[[:blank:]][0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]?,[[:blank:]][1-2]?[0-9]:[0-6][0-9][[:blank:]][AP]M/' file
```

If matching one (or more) digits is good enough (I can't see why not), you can use the shorter regex:

```
awk '/@ [0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+, [1-2]?[0-9]:[0-6][0-9] [AP]M/' file
```

And you can add start `^` and end `$` to make the regex quite more restrictive, if needed.

I am not using `match` for such a simple matching of a line, but the same regex would work perfectly fine with that function.

Comment: This works on mac os. Also [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256343/5395338), and this [regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) for a more detailed explanation of @Isaac use of the `[[:blank:]]` character class, and the related `[[:space:]]` class. Note POSIX compliance :)

Answer (score 1):

- why strictly matching `/\W` (non-word character) before `@` ? as in your text file `@` is at start of the line
- no need to escape the chars as `\@`, `\,`, `:` (they are not special chars)
- calling `match()` is redundant if only need to match a pattern

---

```
$ awk '/^@ [0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M/' file
@ 1/7/18, 4:21 PM
@ 1/7/18, 4:22 PM
@ 1/7/18, 6:12 PM
@ 1/7/18, 8:56 PM
@ 1/7/18, 9:36 PM
@ 1/7/18, 9:46 PM
```

Comment: I need this to work with the `match` stmt as it's part of a larger script.

Comment: Doesn't work on macos: $ awk 'match($0, //^@ [0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M/'/) {print $0}' testfile2.txt -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: Also doesn't work on macos: $ awk '/^@ [0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M/' testfile2.txt gives no output at all